# Output R statistics as organized LaTeX table

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to output a lot of statistics from several data frames, each consisting of multiple values of the respective statistic test. I think R Brew can do this, however I have not found any examples online, and the documentation is extremely limited. Other R table methods will not work, as they're hard coded to accept only certain objects (statistic tests), which do not include my needed non-parametric WMW test.

I have 3 statistical tests that will need to be included into the table. The Shapiro-Wilk test, Welch T-Test, and the WMW test. The first test is run for each distribution, while the other two tests are run comparing two distributions at a time.

There is too much data to provide here as an example, so I will keep the description of the data very limited. Below is an example for only two cases (my LaTeX example: Case A and Case B). For two distributions X and Y:

Shapiro-Wilk test:

```
shap_X <- shapiro.test(val_X$V22)
shap_Y <- shapiro.test(val_Y$V22)
shap_X$statistic = sprintf("%5.3f", shap_X$statistic)
shap_Y$statistic = sprintf("%5.3f", shap_Y$statistic)
shap_X$p.value = sprintf("%.3f", shap_X$p.value)
shap_Y$p.value = sprintf("%.3f", shap_Y$p.value)

#merge shap stats into one data frame for brew??
my_shap_stat <- data.frame(shap_X$statistic)
colnames(my_shap_stat) <- c("A")
my_shap_stat$B <- shap_Y$statistic
my_shap_p <- data.frame(shap_X$p.value)
colnames(my_shap_p) <- c("A")
my_shap_p$B <- shap_Y$p.value
```

How might I take those data frames above `my_shap_stat` and `my_shap_p`, and inject their values into a R Brew LaTeX template? The only example LaTeX Brew template I have is below.

R Brew LaTeX template for some data frame `fit` with column names `A` and `B`:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{l l}
A & <%= fit$A %> \\
B & <%= fit$B %> \\
\end{tabular}
```

My example LaTeX table:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}    
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllllll@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{7}{c}{Title Text}                                                                         \\ \midrule
Statistic & Test & Case A                          & Case B     & Case C     & Case D     & Case E     \\ \midrule
Normality\footnotemark &      &                                 &            &            &            &            \\ \midrule
          & W    & 1.01,1.03                       & 1.32,1.45  & 1.32,1.45  & 1.32,1.45  & 1.32,1.45  \\ \midrule
          & P    & \textless{}.001,\textless{}.001 & 0.233,.536 & 0.233,.536 & 0.233,.536 & 0.233,.536 \\ \midrule
T-Test\footnotemark    &      &                                 &            &            &            &            \\ \midrule
          & T    & 1.02                            & 1.02       & 1.02       & 1.02       & 1.02       \\ \midrule
          & P    & .002                            & .002       & .002       & .002       & .002       \\ \midrule
WMW\footnotemark       &      &                                 &            &            &            &            \\ \midrule
          & W    & 30.55                           & 30.55      & 30.55      & 30.55      & 30.55      \\ \midrule
          & P    & .006                            & .006       & .006       & .006       & .006       \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{tabular}{l}
Content\footnotemark\\
\end{tabular}
\footnotetext[1]{Shapiro-Wilk Normality Test}
\footnotetext[2]{Welch T-Test}
\footnotetext[3]{Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney Rank Sum Test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the R package `stargazer`?

Comment: I have looked at stargazer, but it doesn’t appear to support WMW test. So, I wouldn’t be able to use it. R Brew so far looks to be the best tool to use here, however as I mentioned, I can’t find any information for how to use it to inject data from data frames into LaTeX template tables.